# Android - FQL query to get album photo count

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql

I am using facebook sdk to integrate facebook with my android application. I want to count the number of photos in a album. I am having my album id. 
I need like the following one.

```
SELECT count FROM album WHERE aid = '1232323_1212121';
```

But it returns `count is not a member of the album table.`

How can I get the number of photos in a album?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album), the field in question is `photo_count`.

Comment: Thanks. I got the number of photos in a album using photo_count.